# How to make Bootstrap.css <select> inherit the properties of <input> in CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms

I would like to inherit not only the box size, but also the font type, color etc.
I am calling select similarly to input (with same class) but still not working:

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">

    <select class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter the number of passengers.">
```

Answer (score 1):

Please provide your css class then one can answer.

In this fiddle by given class it is working.

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/352tohbh/`
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom css and put a class name element in those two then call it within your CSS.

**HTML**

```
<input type = "text" class = "inputs" ....>
<select class = "inputs" ....>
```

**CSS**

```
.inputs{ //your style here }
```

or just simply call it from your CSS
**CSS**

```
input[type=text],select{ your style here}
```

I just mean to help. Don't flame me please.